# apostrophe converts to random characters on parsing android

Tags: android, xml

I have been parsing the `xml` from remote server and found an issue the other night.

All the data is parsed well, but an issue is that -

Apostrophe`(')` character gets converted to a random set of characters.

Also, the url of images in the xml are not showing images on the webview , instead shows some blank boxes.

I am loading data on webview as below:

```
String full_desc="// Some text parsed from xml containing apostrophe in it.";
full_desc="<font color='black'>" + full_desc + "</font>";
webview.loadData(full_desc, "text/html; charset=UTF-8", null);
```

Please help !!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you parse the String from the server, you need to give proper escape sequences for the apostrophe to be properly recognised on the client side.

The escape sequence for **`'`** is **`&apos`**.

Try

```
public static String getXMLString(String response) {
    response = response.replace("'", "&apos;");
    return response;
}
```